# Scope of implicit type variables in OCaml constraints

Tags: syntax, types, ocaml, type-inference

In Ocaml you can introduce new type variables inside a constraint, which is useful to enforce type-identities in the type-checker:

```
let f g n = (g (n:'n):'n) ;;
val f : ('n -> 'n) -> 'n -> 'n = <fun>
```

It is obviously possible to re-use these type variables (otherwise it would be a rather pointless exercise). However, since they are not introduced by some special statement, I wonder what there scope is? Is it the enclosing function, let-binding or top-level statement?

Is there a way to limit the scope of such an implicitly introduced type-variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scope of any type variable used in a type constraint is the body of the enclosing let-expression. If an expression is mutually recursive, then the scope is extended to the whole set of mutual recursive expressions. The scope cannot be reduced. Let-expression is a typing primitive. It is not possible to hide or override a type variable.

Whenever a new type variable is introduced, it is looked up in a current typing context. If it was already introduced, then it is unified. Otherwise a new type variable is added to the context. (That can be later used for unification).

An example to clarify the idea:

```
let rec f g h x y = g (x : 'a) + h (y : 'a) and e (x : 'a) = x + 1;;
```

Here, `'a` used to constraint `x` in `e` is the same `'a` that was used to contraint `x` and `y` in the body of function `f`. Since, `x` in `e` is unified with `int` type the unification extends to function `f`, constraining function `g` and `h` to type `int -> int`.

Comment: You are right, of course, it's been a long day. Fixed it. However, you did not really answer my question. It is clear that the scope of these type variables is the whole let-expression in my example, but what is the general rule?

Comment: the general rule is `let expression` or mutual set of `let rec` expressions. This is a typing primitive. I've rewrote the answer. Hope now it will be better.